# Spring Data JPA derived query returns 0 records where as @Query fetches correct record

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My JPA derived method findByBatchIdAndInstitute(Long id, Institute inst) does not fetch correct records. It returns 0 records. However if I use @Query with native query it works fine.

Any idea on why derived method does not fetch records?.
I made sure the variable names "batchId" and "institute" are spelled correctly in the derived method.
I am not able to figure out anything by turning on JPA show sql in console

Below is my Entity details ....

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Batch")
public class BatchEntity implements Serializable{
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long batchId;
    
    private String batchName;
    
    @OneToOne
    private ClassEntity clazz;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = InstituteEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instId")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"batchList", "classList"})
    private InstituteEntity institute;
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Institute")
public class InstituteEntity implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long instId;
    
    private String instituteName;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=BatchEntity.class, mappedBy="institute", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("institute")
    private List<BatchEntity> batchList;
    
}


@Repository
public interface BatchRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchEntity, Long>{
    
    
    Optional<BatchEntity> findByBatchIdAndInstitute(Long batchId, InstituteEntity institute);
    
    @Query(value = 
            "SELECT * FROM batch b, institute i WHERE b.batch_id = :batchId AND i.inst_id = :instituteId", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<BatchEntity> findByBatchIdAndInstituteId(@Param("batchId") Long batchId, @Param("instituteId") Long instituteId);
    
}
```

JPA sql log details ....

```
select institutee0_.inst_id as inst_id1_3_0_, institutee0_.institute_name as institut2_3_0_ from institute institutee0_ where institutee0_.inst_id=?
select batchentit0_.batch_id as batch_id1_0_, batchentit0_.batch_name as batch_na2_0_, batchentit0_.clazz_class_id as clazz_cl3_0_, batchentit0_.inst_id as inst_id4_0_ from batch batchentit0_ where batchentit0_.batch_id=? and batchentit0_.inst_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = 
        "SELECT * FROM batch b, institute i WHERE b.batch_id = :batchId AND i.inst_id = :instituteId", 
        nativeQuery = true)
```

Look if this native query is correct, then the query getting  SELECT *(all) records from database. *(all) means you should get a `List<BatchEntity>` from this query

Declare it `List<BatchEntity>` , i think it should solve the issue

Comment: If I am not wrong * represents all columns. The query result may or may not give a set of rows. The query above is working fine for me with output as Optional<>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Spring Data JPA derived queries really work with complext Objects as arguments of the methods. What Spring Data JPA is capable of handling is nested data, so try the following instead:

```java
Optional<BatchEntity> findByBatchIdAndInstituteInstId(Long batchId, Long instituteId);
```

Comment: This too fetches 0 records for me. I have come across derived queries that contain complex arguments that work. For ex.
public Chapters findByChapterIdAndSubjectAndClassType(Long chapterId, Subject subject, ClassType classType);
In this case the relationship is OneToOne. But in case where I am facing issue it is having OneToMany and ManyToOne bidirectional relationship

Comment: That is indeed weird, it should work. If you use only `findByBatchId(Long batchId)` or `findByInstituteInstId(Long instituteId)`does it fetch anything?

Comment: findByBatchId(Long batchId)  works fine.
findByInstituteInstId(Long instituteId) doesn't work. I am not sure if this syntax is correct.
findByInstitute(Institute institute) doesn't work. This is the real concern for me. Is it got to do with how Institute and Batch are related to each other.
Since findByChapterIdAndSubjectAndClassType(Long chapterId, Subject subject, ClassType classType) works fine with "complex" arguments Subject and ClassType I expected even Institute to work as well.

Comment: The syntax is fine. I am starting to think that the issue is how the entities relate to each other, but I can't find anything in the code that seems wrong.